# Protractor - Ignore Synchronisation flag

Tags: protractor

I have started doing a POC on Protractor as our e2e automation testing tool.
Our application is designed in angular which makes it a perfect fit.

However, I need to login via google which is a non-angular website and therefore at the start of my test I state

> browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

Then I go to

> 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin'

Enter my google credentials and click on signin

At this point I try to go to my application's URL, which is an angular application so I was hoping to turn

> browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;

All the the above steps are part of a beforeEach so that I can login before each test

But when I turn ignoreSynchronization to false, all my tests start failing.
On the other hand, if I don't turn it to false,  I am compelled to use a lot of browser.sleeps as Protractor is still treating it as a non-angular app and does not wait for angular to load fully

I have also tried to put the ignoreSynchronization = false in each individual test as opposed to beforeEach but even then all my tests start failing.

Below is my beforeEach code

```
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
      browser.get(googlelogin);
      email.sendKeys('username');
      next.click();
      browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(pwd), 5000);
      pwd.sendKeys('pwd');
      signin.click();
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
      browser.driver.get(tdurl);
```

Comment: What if you switch your last two steps?  get the next url (the angular page), and then set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false`;  Also you could add one more expected condition for an element on the angular page just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to fix:

- wait for the "click" to go through
- use `browser.get()` on the Angular Page

Here are the modifications:

```
signin.click().then(function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    browser.get(tdurl);
    browser.waitForAngular();  // might not be necessary
});
```

You may also add a [wait](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) with an Expected Condition to wait for the login step to be completed - say, wait for a specific URL, or page title, or an element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Reconciliation_verifyExapanedDatainExpanedRow: function (HeaderName, texttobepresent) {
        browser.waitForAngular().then(function () {
            var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
            var columnHeaderActive = GUtils.$locatorXpath('//p-datatable//span[contains(text(),"' + HeaderName + '")]/..//span[@class="ui-cell-data"][contains(.,\'' + texttobepresent + '\')]');
            browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(GUtils.$element(columnHeaderActive)), GUtils.shortDynamicWait()).then(function () {
           console.log('PASS');
            }, function (err) {
                       console.log('FAIL');
              });
        });
    },
```